# Bootstrap table columns to be collapsible at mobile view

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am trying to design a table wherein at mobile view the last two to three columns which are not visible in mobile view should be made collapsible using only CSS and if possible Javascript not jQuery. This is to be done for salesforce web application so no jQuery is allowed. Any help would great.

Tried with this example: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwPVNW

This is somewhat similar but I am unable to break the last two to three columns data and show it below.

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table tr {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table thead {
    display: none;
  }
  table tr {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  }
  table td {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  table td:before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Payment</th>
      <th>Issue Date</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Period</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Payment">Payment #1</td>
      <td data-label="Issue Date">02/01/2015</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,311</td>
      <td data-label="Period">01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Payment">Payment #2</td>
      <td data-label="Issue Date">03/01/2015</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$3,211</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2015 - 02/28/2015</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So in mobile you want the last two columns (Amount and Period) to be collapsible? Explain the desired behavior a bit more please.

Comment: just a moment will upload picture